# Parametrize sphere over complex projective line

Tags: geometry

Elementary question which I sort of skipped and am now banging my head on: given the equation for a general 2- sphere 
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 = r^2$$

I need to construct a parametrization by the **complex** projective line.

I've just had a total conceptual block on this - I can do the algebra necessary to get it so that we have a point at the affine origin of co-ordinates in $\mathbb{A}^3$, but I just can't really get any intuition for what a complex homogeneous co-ordinate $(s:t)$ is really doing.

The problem I'm having is that I've got four variables to play with and only three that need to be parametrized. Or have I got the wrong end of the stick here?

Comment: Just to make sure, if I understood correctly the notion of "parametrization by the complex projective line". Do you need an isomorphism between $S^2$ and $\mathbb{CP}^1$ ?

Comment: Well, a general sphere rather than necessarily $S^2$, yes (I have an actual equation but I need to work through the calculation myself so I don't want to be explicit about it). I have been asked to give the parametrization in homogeneous co-ordinates, so I presume I need to work it through 'both ways' and in particular show the inverse from a point on the sphere to a point in $\mathbb{CP}^1$

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the problem to $S^2$ because you can always reparametrize your equation above and get $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Comment: True. It still leaves me with the basic conceptual problem - I have some point on the sphere and I want an equation, I guess, in terms of $x,y,z$ for some point $(s:t) \in \mathbb{CP}^1$. Is that just stereographic projection? What happens to the 'fourth variable' in one of my complex homogeneous co-ordinates?

Comment: On the one hand, you have 3 variables which are dependent by a single equation which "kills" one variable, so you have actually 2 variables to parametrize the sphere. On the other hand, you have $[s_1+s_2i:t_1+t_2i]$ which are identified by actions of $\lambda_1+\lambda_2 i$, where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$, so they "kill" 2 of your variables, and you got again 2 variables to parametrize $\mathbb{CP}^1$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'identified by actions of...'?

Comment: Oh hang on - it's just a multiplicative action, right? So I can reduce my homogeneous co-ordinates to $[1: t_1 + t_2i]$...

Comment: You can cover the projective line by 2 of such charts, another one is $[s_1+s_2i:1]$. Similarly you cover your sphere with 2 charts which are the stereographic projections from the north and south poles. In the first case, you have an isomorphism to $\mathbb{C}^1$, in the second case, an isomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which are the same.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a think about this,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75104/discussion-between-matt-bright-and-mihail).